# Javascript function returns false when it should be true from an if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return

I want to write a function that takes a letter as an argument and returns true if it's a vowel and false otherwise.

I've set an array of letters and used an if statement to pick up the vowels but the function returns false weather its a vowel or consonant?

Any idea on how i can get the function to return true when passing a vowel.

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 
'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'];

function max(ltr) {


for (var item = 0; item < arr.length; item++) {
    if (item == 'a' || item == 'e' || item == 'i' || item == 'o' || item == 'u') {
        return true;
    } else {
    return false;
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

What your function does is check the number zero against the list of vowels, and immediately return `false` (since `0` does not equal any of the vowels). It never even looks at `ltr`.

You need to fix the function, and to move the loop outside.

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, you are comparing an `Int` (`item`) with strings.

Try this:

```
if (ltr == 'a' || ltr == 'e' || ltr == 'i' || ltr == 'o' || ltr == 'u')
```

This way you can skip the entire `arr`, unless you use that for other reasons as well. I would not know why, though.

Another (easier) implementation would be to use [Regular Expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp):

```
function isVowel(letter) {
    return /^[aeuio]$/.test(letter)
}
```

This tests whether `ltr` is matched by the `RegExp`, and whether it is a single character.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing character with int ( item)
at the first step item = 0;
it's not a character and it returns false

Answer (score 0):

item is int, you check it like it is string. Use toString(N) to convert it into another base or use arr[item] to get letter from arr.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will work :

```
var vowelsconsonants = function (vowel,consonant) {

if (vowel.length > 0 && consonant.length > 0) {
  if (vowel === 'a' || vowel === 'e'|| vowel === 'i' || vowel === 'o'  || vowel ==='u') {
        return true;
  } else {
        return false;
  }
} else {
  return false;
}
};
```

Give it a try...

Answer (score -1):

You need to use the index of item to return the values from your array i.e.

```
if (arr[item] == 'a' || arr[item] == 'e' || arr[item] == 'i' || arr[item] == 'o' || arr[item] == 'u')
```

Comment: This would just return true always, since the first match is an 'a'.

Comment: This was written in the context of the above being within the for loop as described in the original question.  Thus it is correct.